# How to find referrer URL while using htaccess 404 redirect?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-referer

I've used the code below to create a custom 404 message (page not found) using a .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 https://%{HTTP_HOST}/404.php
```

It works well, but I want to know what was the wrong URL that caused this redirection. In other words, I need to fetch **HTTP referer** while user is in 404.php. So I have used `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` in 404.php, but it does not return anything.
Where did I have mistakes? And what is your solutions to solve this problem?

Comment: Don't trust the referrer-header. Some (qutie a lot) browers/routers/vpns/firewalls actually clears the referrer-header for privacy reasons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `http://` from 404 handler and have it like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

The URL that is causing 404 is available to you in `404.php` using:

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
```

When `http://` ise used in 404 handler server performs full redirection and you loose original `REQUEST_URI`.